# Remove bold style for chapter names in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

**Problem:**

I wish to have bold style for certain chapter names but not for others.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%: ----------------------- Table of contents ------------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To get the second chapter name in the table of contents in normal style.

Comment: Is there a criterion to determine which should be bold (eg. numbered chapters)?

Comment: @Bernard No criteria, but if it can facilitate a smooth solution, all chapters at the end which I wish to have in normal style are added with `\addcontentsline`- is it possible to modify it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way: Writing the change of the `\cftchap...` etc. macros to the toc and make the font bold or just `\normalfont`.

I've adapted this for the page font as well as for the leaders...

The macro `\enableboldchapterintoc` enables this globally until `\disableboldchapterintoc` is used. Reenable it with another `\enableboldchapterintoc` etc, where needed.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


\newcommand*{\enableboldchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont\protect\bfseries}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont\protect\bfseries}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\bfseries\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% dot leaders in bold
}
\newcommand*{\disableboldchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\normalfont\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% 
}



%: ----------------------- Table of contents ------------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\fi}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold


\begin{document}
\enableboldchapterintoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\disableboldchapterintoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test Chapter Two}

\enableboldchapterintoc

\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on, hats off to you sir.

Comment: @kexxcream: You're welcome. Happy TeXing...

Answer (score 2):

You noted in the comments that the normal style chapters are added with `\addcontentsline`. Because you do not want to format them like normal `chapter`s, you can create a new kind of TOC entry instead of reusing `chapter`.
To do this with `tocloft` you can mostly copy the definitions for `chapter` from `titletoc.sty`. Here I used the name `chapterNB`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\l@chapterNB}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip \cftbeforechapNBskip
    {\leftskip \cftchapNBindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftchapNBindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftchapNBnumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftchapNBpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftchapNBaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftchapNBaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftchapNBfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftchapNBfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}%
\newlength{\cftbeforechapNBskip}
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapNBskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\newlength{\cftchapNBindent}
  \setlength{\cftchapNBindent}{\cftchapindent}
\newlength{\cftchapNBnumwidth}
  \setlength{\cftchapNBnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}
\let\cftchapNBfont\cftchapfont
\let\cftchapNBpresnum\cftchappresnum
\let\cftchapNBaftersnum\cftchapaftersnum
\let\cftchapNBaftersnumb\cftchapaftersnumb
\newcommand{\cftchapNBleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftchapNBdotsep}}
\let\cftchapNBdotsep\cftchapdotsep
\let\cftchapNBpagefont\cftchappagefont
\let\cftchapNBafterpnum\cftchapafterpnum
\newcommand{\cftchapNBfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftchapNBleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{\cftchapNBpagefont #1}\cftchapNBafterpnum\par
}
\makeatletter
```

After that, you can change the formatting of the new `chapterNB`:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
```

To add a "chapter" in normal (non-bold) style to the table of contents, you can use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapterNB}{Test Chapter Two}
```

Combined this results in

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%: ----------------------- Table of contents ------------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\l@chapterNB}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip \cftbeforechapNBskip
    {\leftskip \cftchapNBindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftchapNBindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftchapNBnumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftchapNBpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftchapNBaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftchapNBaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftchapNBfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftchapNBfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}%
\newlength{\cftbeforechapNBskip}
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapNBskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\newlength{\cftchapNBindent}
  \setlength{\cftchapNBindent}{\cftchapindent}
\newlength{\cftchapNBnumwidth}
  \setlength{\cftchapNBnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}
\let\cftchapNBfont\cftchapfont
\let\cftchapNBpresnum\cftchappresnum
\let\cftchapNBaftersnum\cftchapaftersnum
\let\cftchapNBaftersnumb\cftchapaftersnumb
\newcommand{\cftchapNBleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftchapNBdotsep}}
\let\cftchapNBdotsep\cftchapdotsep
\let\cftchapNBpagefont\cftchappagefont
\let\cftchapNBafterpnum\cftchapafterpnum
\newcommand{\cftchapNBfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftchapNBleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{\cftchapNBpagefont #1}\cftchapNBafterpnum\par
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapNBleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapterNB}{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output]