# How to style specific chapter in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

I have the following code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, times new roman, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\addChapter}[1]{\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addChapter{Costum1}
\addChapter{Costum2}
\addChapter{Costum3}
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document
```

which gives [image]

Notice that Costum1, Costum2 and Costum3 follows the style of A, B, C. What I want is Costum1, Costum2, and Costum3 to have no style at all, just plain 12 pt times new roman, no bold, no italic, with one spacing.

Below is what roughly I want ( I make this using word )
[image]
Also, I dont need the dot. It's there because it's default on Word.

Edit : I do need the dot, but only for custom1, custom2 and custom3.

\hline

After trying the solution in [Remove bold style for chapter names in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419555/remove-bold-style-for-chapter-names-in-table-of-contents?rq=1)
I was able to unbold custom1, custom2 and custom3 in TOC. Here's the full code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, times new roman, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\addChapter}[1]{\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\enableboldchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont\protect\bfseries}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont\protect\bfseries}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\bfseries\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% dot leaders in bold
}
\newcommand*{\disableboldchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\normalfont\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% 
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\disableboldchapterintoc
\addChapter{Costum1}
\addChapter{Costum2}
\addChapter{Costum3}
\enableboldchapterintoc

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

How do I reduce the space in the red line?

Comment: What is the purpose of `\addChapter`? It is not working since `hyperref` is not loaded (so `\phantomsection` fails) and the `\addChapter` calls are at the wrong place... `\chapter` adds the correct ToC line already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Yeah, I forgot to add hyperref, but somehow it works. What I want is to have costum style chapter title in the TOC. So, costum1, costum2 and costum3 will have its own style and will not follow the usual chapter style like A,B,and C. If I use the usual chapter \chapter command on costum1 , costum2 and costum3. The toc of costum1, costum2, and costum3 will be numbered, I want to make them unnumbered and have simple style (12 pt times new roman). Do you have any other idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: You mean `custom`, not `costum`, by the way ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was coming across one question that you answered https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419555/remove-bold-style-for-chapter-names-in-table-of-contents?rq=1  I was able to unbold  custom1, custom2, and custom3 chapter. The only problem left is the spacing between custom1 and costum2 is too big, also applies to custom 3. I was wondering if you know how to make it smaller, basically singlespacing for all these custom-styled chapter? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've updated my question